# How to sort parent items in chronological order from first to oldest like instagram Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello stackoverflow I have a problem with this ordering the items I have inside "post" which is a "parent" I need the items inside parent
Which are id generated by the push method are ordered in chronological order

Try with this method: .orderByKey (), I already read the documentation and tells me to use that method but it does not work

This is my database example in a photo, it is well explained what I need to order
[My database photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Pgx.png)

These are the methods and references that I use:

the adapter method:

```
  private void setupAdapter() {
    mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.row_post,
            PostHolder.class,
            FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().orderByKey()
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostHolder viewHolder, final Post model, int position) {
            Post mPost = new Post();

            viewHolder.setNumComments(String.valueOf(model.getNumComments()));
            viewHolder.setNumLikes(String.valueOf(model.getNumLikes()));
            viewHolder.setNumDislikes(String.valueOf(model.getNumDislikes()));
            viewHolder.setTime(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeCreated()));
            viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText(model.getUsername());
            if(viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView == null){
                viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText("Anonymous");
            }
            viewHolder.setPostText(model.getPostText());


                final  StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                        .getReference(model.getPostImageUrl());


                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(storageReference).into(viewHolder.postDisplayImageView); ... remainder of code
```

i tried this

```
  mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(
        Post.class,
        R.layout.row_post,
        PostHolder.class,
        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().getParent().orderByKey
```

But doing so does not receive the data to be rendered in the adapter in populate viewHolder

the utils:

```
 public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
     return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("posts");
  }
  public static Query getPostQuery() {
    return getPostRef().orderByChild("timeCreated");
 }
 public static DatabaseReference getMyPostRef() {
     return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("myPosts")
             .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution, but it was difficult is ironic that it is very easy

set the `LinearLayoutManager` like this

```
 mPostRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_post);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mPostRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    setupAdapter();
    mPostRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
```

this is all